# React and Firebase - how to count based on property value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, state

I am trying to count done tasks. I am fetching whole data because I am also rendering it. After componentDidMount I have all data stored in state object like so:

[image]

**The componentDidMount looks like this:**

```js
  componentDidMount () {
    const dataGoalRef = dbRef.child('goals/'+this.state.uid+'/'+this.state.currentGoalId);
    dataGoalRef.on('value', snap => {
        this.setState({
          dataGoal: snap.val(),
          currentGoalId: this.props.match.params.goalId,
        });
    });
  }
```

I am already counting the tasks with `{this.state.allTasksCount++}` but it fires every time component gets rendered it.

```js
render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <main className="content">
          <p>{this.state.dataGoal.description}</p><br /><br />


            { this.state.dataGoal.milestones &&
              Object.keys(this.state.dataGoal.milestones).map( (milestoneKey) => {
              const milestonesData = this.state.dataGoal.milestones[milestoneKey];
              console.log(this.doneTasksFromDataGoal());

              return <div className="milestone-wrap" key={milestoneKey}>
                       <label className="milestone-label truncate">{milestonesData.name}</label>

                       {Object.keys(milestonesData.tasks)
                         .filter( (taskKey, index) => {
                           {this.state.allTasksCount++}
                           return milestonesData.tasks[taskKey].done === false;
                         })
                         .map( (taskKey) => {

                           {this.state.todoTasksCount++}
                           return <div className="task clearfix" key={taskKey}>

                                       <input
                                         className="checkbox-rounded"
                                         name="done"
                                         type="checkbox"
                                         checked={milestonesData.tasks[taskKey].done}
                                         onChange={(e) => this.handleInputChange(e, milestoneKey, taskKey)} />
                                       <div className="task-content">
                                         <p className="task-name truncate">{milestonesData.tasks[taskKey].name}</p>
                                         <p className="task-date">{milestonesData.tasks[taskKey].finishDate}</p>
                                       </div>
                                  </div>

                         })}

                     </div>

            })}

        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

What is the best way to get the number of done or not done tasks and keep it in state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a really verbose solution to iterate the milestones and tasks and increment a counter inside of the `render()` function:

```
render() {
    var doneCount = 0;
    var milestones = this.state.dataGoal.milestones;

    Object.keys(milestones).forEach(function(milestoneKey) {
        Object.keys(milestones[milestoneKey].tasks).forEach(function(taskKey) {
            if (milestones[milestoneKey].tasks[taskKey].done) {
                doneCount += 1;
            }
        });
    });

    return (
        <div>Done: {doneCount}</div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Your solution works just fine. Thank you very much. Only one retype is in `if (milestones[key].tasks[taskKey].done) {` it should be `if (milestones[milestoneKey].tasks[taskKey].done) {`. Anyway thanks a lot @Troy.

Answer (score 0):

Try **componentWillRecieveProps**. It will be called whenever props are changed after mounting has been completed. Also here you can compare previous and next props.
And this is the preferred place to call setState, by using which you can update done counter.

Please comment if you need detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks, @Shahzad for your answer. I have updated my question. I still don't really know how to do so.